# while look inside of a switch statement (double breaking)

Tags: c, operating-system

kinda silly control flow question:

basically I have something like the following,

```
switch(r){
case(0):
  while (x != TRUE) {
     yield();
     break;
  }
  do_important_work();
  break;
}
```

if the condition is met (i.e. if x != TRUE) I want this thread to just yield, and stop execution at this spot in the code (i.e. i do a kernel level context switch), and allow some other process to run, to be tried again later. The problem is that the break inside the while loop just breaks out of the while loop, not the entire switch statement. What i really want is to perform the yield, and then break out and allow another context switch to happen.

Does this make sense? It's way to late and I cant for the life of me find a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the question how to break out of the `switch` from within the loop? Then use a `goto`.

Comment: use a `flag` variable, update from `while` loop (before `break`ing)  and put the rest of the code under that `flag` check. I personally do not prefer using `goto`

Comment: sorry maybe I am not grasping the question correctly, but wouldn't using `break` to get out of the loop followed by another `break` immediately after the closing brace of the wile break you out of the switch?

Comment: No, it doesn't make any sense. Why have a  `while` if you have a non-conditional `break` inside it? The loop adds nothing.

Comment: just delete the `break` statement in your `while` loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That construct looks painful. You immediately break from the while, so it doesn't actually loop. In which case you can just use an if, like this:

```
if (!x)
{
    yield();
}
else
{
    do_important_work();
}
break;
```

Comment: whoa was def being sleepy and kinda stupid last night.